# Android IBM Watson visual recognition service

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

IBM Watson has a Visual Recognition service: http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition.html

Here is the API explorer to test calls to the API:
http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v3/

The tutorials and API reference are available in the documentation.

I am trying to use the service in order to retrieve the JSON data response through android. However, after debugging, it keeps showing error 404. I am completely lost on how to fix this issue.

If you are going to run the following code, please replace `api_key` in Main_activity.java with your own key. This key is generated when you create your own service for IBM Watson's Visual Recognition service on IBM Bluemix.

Here is my MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.innam.httpapptotestrestservice;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView etResponse;
    TextView tvIsConnected;
    TextView imageRespone;
    ImageView imgPreview;
//    VideoView vidPreview;

    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    private Uri fileUri;

    static String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Watson";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get reference to the views
        etResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etResponse);
        tvIsConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIsConnected);
        imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
        imageRespone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ImgResponse);

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
//        mediaController.setAnchorView(vidPreview);
//        vidPreview.setMediaController(mediaController);

        // check if you are connected or not
        if (isConnected()) {
            tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
            tvIsConnected.setText("You are conncted");

        } else {
            tvIsConnected.setText("You are NOT conncted");
        }

        // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
        new HttpAsyncTaskOne().execute();
    }

    public static String GET(String url) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private class HttpAsyncTaskOne extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Hi!", "Please wait your response is about to generate");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            //return GET(urls[0]);

            return getResponseOne();
        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            pd.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String formattedResult="";
            String classifer_id="" ;
            String name="";
            String owner="";
            String status="";
            String created ="";
            String classesobj="";

            try{
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);

                classifer_id = jObj.optString("classifier_id");
                name = jObj.optString("name");
                owner = jObj.optString("owner");
                status = jObj.optString("status");
                created = jObj.optString("created");

                JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.optJSONArray("classes");

                //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
                for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    classesobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("class");

                    //classesobj += jObj.optString("class");
                }

                formattedResult = "{ \n" + "    classifer_id: "+ classifer_id
                                                + ",\n  name: "+ name
                                                + ",\n  owner: "+ owner
                                                + ",\n  status: "+ status
                                                + ",\n  created: "+ created
                                                + ",\n  classes: [\n"+
                                                            "{ class: " + classesobj + "}\n" +
                                                                "       ] \n }";
            }
            catch(JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            etResponse.setText(formattedResult);
        }
    }

    /**
     * https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classifiers?
     * api_key=*****

     * @return
     */

    private String getResponseOne() {
        //String endPointUrl = AppConstants.BASE_URL + "";

        /*String params = "api_key=*********" +
                "&url=http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/orange-apple-banana-isolated-white-background-51942284.jpg" +
                "&classifier_ids=default,fruits_960559343" +
                "&owners=me,IBM" +
                "&threshold=0.2" +
                "&version=2016-05-20";*/

        String postParams = "api_key=**********" +
                "&version=2016-05-19" +
                "&negative_examples=negative_examples.zip" +
                "&classname_positive_examples=baypay_positive_examples.zip&name=baypay";


        //String url = "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?";
        String url = "https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classifiers?"+postParams;

//        String params ="api_key=********" +
//                "version=2016-05-19";
//
//        String url = "https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classifiers/baypay_309108553?" ;

        ServiceHandler serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler(this);

        try {
//            return serviceHandler.doPost(url, params);
            return serviceHandler.doGet(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "Response Not returned";
    }


    public void openCamera(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Launching camera app to record video
     */
//    public void openVideo(View v) {
//        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
//
//        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
//
//        // set video quality
//        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
//
//        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
//        // name
//
//        // start the video capture Intent
//        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
//    }

    String photoPath = "";

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) //what to do once the image has been captured
    {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                // successfully captured the image
                // launching upload activity
                //launchUploadActivity(true);

                // bimatp factory

                photoPath = fileUri.getPath();

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
                // images
                options.inSampleSize = 8;

                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);

                imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                vidPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

//next parse result string

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

        }
//        else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
//            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
//
//                // video successfully recorded
//                // launching upload activity
//
//                imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                vidPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                vidPreview.setVideoPath(fileUri.getPath());
//                // start playing
//                vidPreview.start();
//
//
//            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
//
//                // user cancelled recording
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//                        "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
//                        .show();
//
//            } else {
//                // failed to record video
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//                        "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
//                        .show();
//            }
//        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
//        if(vidPreview != null && vidPreview.isPlaying())
//        {
//            vidPreview.pause();
//        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

//        if(vidPreview != null && vidPreview.isPlaying())
//        {
//            vidPreview.stopPlayback();
//        }
    }

    /**
     * Creating file uri to store image/video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /**
     * returning image / video
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("IMG Capture", "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        }
//         else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
//            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
//                    + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
//        }
        else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }


    public void uploadImage(View view)
    {
        new HttpAsyncTaskTwo().execute();
    }

    private class HttpAsyncTaskTwo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Uploading image!", "Please Wait..");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
        {
            return getResponseTwo();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            pd.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            imageRespone.setText(result);
        }
    }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        private String getResponseTwo()
        {
            String result;

            String testName = fileUri.getPathSegments().get(fileUri.getPathSegments().size()-1);

            //setup params
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("api_key", "******");
            params.put("images_file", testName);
            params.put("parameters", "{\"urls\": [], \"classifier_ids\": [\"baypay_1337105903\"], \"owners\": [\"0c9e0d07-7000-4b60-9181-b2e1d0596a30\", \"me\"], \"threshold\": 0.4}");
            params.put("Accept-Language", "en");
            params.put("version", "2016-05-19");

            ServiceHandler serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler(this);

            try
            {
                return serviceHandler.multipartRequest("https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify", params, fileUri.getPath(), "image", "image/jpg");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "Response Not returned";
        }
    }
```

Here is the ServiceHandler.java file:

```
package com.innam.httpapptotestrestservice;

import android.content.Context;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class ServiceHandler {
    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    String filename = "myJsonResponse.txt";
    String outputString = "Hello world!";
    File myDir;
    static final int READ_BLOCK_SIZE = 100;

    Context context;

    public ServiceHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        myDir = context.getFilesDir();
    }

    public String doGet(String GET_URL) throws IOException {
        URL obj = new URL(GET_URL);

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        con.setConnectTimeout(150000);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode);

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            // success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;

            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }

            in.close();

            // print result
            //System.out.println(response.toString());

            return response.toString();
        } else {
            System.out.println("GET request not worked: Response Code: " + responseCode);

            return "GET request not worked: Response Code: " + responseCode;
        }
    }

    public String doPost(String POST_URL, String POST_PARAMS) throws IOException {
        URL obj = new URL(POST_URL);

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        // For POST only - START
        con.setDoOutput(true);

        con.setConnectTimeout(150000);

        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();

        os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());

        os.flush();

        os.close();

        // For POST only - END

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            //success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;

            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }

            in.close();

            // print result
            //System.out.println(response.toString());

            /*try 
            {
                File respFile = new File(myDir + "/text/", filename);

                if (respFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()) 
                {
                    outputString = response.toString();
                    respFile.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(respFile);

                    fos.write(outputString.getBytes());

                    System.out.println(myDir + " /" + filename);

                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } */

            return response.toString();
        } else {
            System.out.println("POST request not worked: Response Code: " + responseCode);

            return "POST request not worked: Response Code: " + responseCode;
        }
    }

    public String multipartRequest(String urlTo, Map<String, String> parmas, String filepath,
                                   String filefield, String fileMimeType) throws Exception {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "*****";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";

        String result = "";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        String[] q = filepath.split("/");
        int idx = q.length - 1;

        try {
            File file = new File(filepath);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            URL url = new URL(urlTo);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Multipart HTTP Client 1.0");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + filefield + "\"; filename=\"" + q[idx] + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + fileMimeType + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd);

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // Upload POST Data
            Iterator<String> keys = parmas.keySet().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                String value = parmas.get(key);

                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/json" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(value);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            int respCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            System.out.println("Response Code: " + respCode);

            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            result = this.convertStreamToString(inputStream);

            fileInputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //logger.error(e);
            //throw new CustomException(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is the CustomException.java file:

```
package com.innam.httpapptotestrestservice;

import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by Innam on 8/5/2016.
 */
public class CustomException extends Throwable {
    public CustomException(String s) {
        Log.e("CustomException", s);
    }
}
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.innam.httpapptotestrestservice">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvIsConnected"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#FF0000"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:text="is connected? " />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="JSON reult after the service has been trained"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/etResponse"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
                    </TextView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Open Camera"
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:onClick="openCamera"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgPreview"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="165dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="UPLOAD"
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:onClick="uploadImage"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="JSON reult after image has been uploaded"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ImgResponse"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
                </TextView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You might be interested in using the [Java SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk), [Android SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk), or [Android Speech SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-android-sdk).

Comment: Take a look at my answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/37313091/456564

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main part of your problem is that you have the wrong URL in your code - both the wrong domain (watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net) and the wrong path (`classify` vs `classifiers`) - the correct one is commented out.

But, as Glenn and German pointed out in comments, there are SDKs available that make the entire process much simpler, so I would strongly advise taking that route.